# Show that unimodal distribution variance is smaller than uniform distribution

Tags: variance, uniform-distribution

Let $f(x)$ be a unimodal distribution on bounded interval $[-1,1]$. Can we show that the variance is upper bounded by variance of Unif$[-1,1]$?

Comment: Am I right in assuming $f$ is the density -- so that the distribution has a density, and it's, eg, strictly increasing for $x$ below the mode and strictly decreasing for $x$ above the mode? If discrete distributions are allowed the claim is false.